# Misunderstanding of the gradient calculation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to understand how loss_metric class in dlib calculates the gradient. Here is the code([full version](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/eb08cfc627b9972e82a95504cea318d17a34d3e1/dlib/dnn/loss.h#L918)):

```
// It should be noted that the derivative of length(x-y) with respect
// to the x vector is the unit vector (x-y)/length(x-y).  If you stare
// at the code below long enough you will see that it's just an
// application of this formula.
if (x_label == y_label)
{
    // Things with the same label should have distances < dist_thresh between
    // them.  If not then we experience non-zero loss.
    if (d2 < dist_thresh-margin)//d2 - distance between x and y samples.
    {
        gm[r*temp.num_samples() + c] = 0;
    }
    else
    {
   // The whole objective function is multiplied by this to scale the loss
   // relative to the number of things in the mini-batch.
   // scale = 0.5/num_pos_samps;
        loss += scale*(d2 - (dist_thresh-margin));
        //r - x sample index, c - y sample index
        gm[r*temp.num_samples() + r] += scale/d2;
        gm[r*temp.num_samples() + c] = -scale/d2;
    }
}
else
{
    // Things with different labels should have distances > dist_thresh between
    // them.  If not then we experience non-zero loss.
    if (d2 > dist_thresh+margin || d2 > neg_thresh)
    {
        gm[r*temp.num_samples() + c] = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        loss += scale*((dist_thresh+margin) - d2);
        // don't divide by zero (or a really small number)
        d2 = std::max(d2, 0.001f);
        gm[r*temp.num_samples() + r] -= scale/d2;
        gm[r*temp.num_samples() + c] = scale/d2;
    }
}

//...
// gemm - matrix multiplication
// grad - final gradient
// grad_mul - gm
// output_tensor - output tensor of the last layer
tt::gemm(0, grad, 1, grad_mul, false, output_tensor, false);
```

Let's look at the loss for the same classes (1030 line), I think the gradient of `scale*(d2 - (dist_thresh-margin))` should be equal to the gradient of `C1*(||X1 - X2|| - (C2-C3))`, where CN - constant, and XN - output vector, so their gradient should be = `C1` for X1 and `-C1` for X2, but instead of this, we get some another calculations on the lines 1031, 1032, 1056.

Same for the gradient for the different classes (starting from 1048 line).

Unfortunately, even hint in the first comment does not make it clearer. I don't have enough experience for understanding this, but I think some slightly more experienced person can show where I made a mistake.

**So, what exactly gradient formula is used here? How did we get it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't read the entire code but it seems the formula used is related to the following

$$\|x-y\|=\sqrt{\sum (x_n-y_n)^2}$$
$$\frac{\partial c_1(\|x-y\|-(c_2-c_3))}{\partial x_n}=\frac{c_1}{\|x-y\|}\frac{\partial \sum (x_n-y_n)^2}{\partial x_n}=\frac{c_1}{\|x-y\|}(x_n-y_n)$$

${c_1}/{\|x-y\|}$ on the right hand side should be the `scale/d2` in the code.

**Update**

We have a couple of positive and negative pairs after computing the distance between each pair, we get a list of distances. The purpose of this loss is to let positive pairs have smaller distances (below some threshold) and negative pair to have larger distances (above some threshold). So it becomes rather similar to a binary classification problem (below some threshold is positive, above is negative).

We can give the misclassified pairs a loss then that could be `||X1 - X2|| - dist_thresh`. In such case, if all the positive distances are `dist_thresh-0.0001` and all the negative distances are `dist_thresh+0.0001`, there won't be any loss anymore but the distances between positive and negative pairs are still pretty close (differed by only 0.0002). To address this we can add a margin term to the loss, which turns out to be `||X1 - X2|| - (dist_thresh +/- margin)`.

The `scale` parameter is just the reciprocal of the number of pairs, so that multiplying it gives the average loss of the batch.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! I just have three questions: can you write what exactly will be on the `d(sum[(xn - yn)^2])/d(xn)` place? Because I'm not sure about my calculations. In the triplet loss network we have 3 gradients(1 gradient per sample), but here we have several passes of loss and gradient calculations per one sample. So which exactly gradient calculates this formula(only x and/or y? Or something else?)? And should we sum all gradients for specific sample after all passes? These steps look unclear for me.

Comment: @don-prog hi I extended the formula a bit. I'm not clear about the whole process either though summing all gradients might sound like the right thing to do.

Comment: Thanks again! I think now almost all clear! Just a couple of questions: how we get `c1`, `c2`, `c3` in this formula and what is this? Also, can you share paper about this gradient? _Sorry for many questions, I tried to solve gradients before, but it's not so trivial on practice._

Comment: @don-prog hi it seems posted another question about that before, I left some comments there

Comment: Thanks for your answers and links, I already saw this paper. Also dlib library uses custom implementation of triplet net: the batch can consist of several samples of several classes(not only + and -), but I think it does not matter for us now. Anyway unfortunately the main questions are still unclear for me: **1. What are the `c1`, `c2`, `c3`? 2. And how we get them in this formula?**

Comment: @don-prog hi I just added that in the answer

Comment: Sorry for such a long delay! I had month of exams. I just want to say that everything is clear and of course correct. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @don-prog No problem! good luck with your exams :)